# How to place while loop inside Asynctask - Android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, while-loop

I have a asynctask which uses a json function in the doInBackground() and it returns the variables to onPostExecute. The problem is I want the json function to be in a while loop, Every time it goes in the loop it collects a comment. So I could have 15 comments and I want to send them all to onPostExecute to be placed into views. Here is my code

```
     class loadComments extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, String, List<String>> {
             DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());





            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            }


            protected List<String> doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
            //do your work here
                List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
             int i = 0;
                while (i < 5 ){
                JSONObject json2 = CollectComments.collectComments(usernameforcomments, offsetNumber);
                result = json2;
                results.add(result);
                i++;
                }


                return results;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<String> results) {
                try {  
                    if (json2.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) { 
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res2 = json2.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res2) == 1){ 

                                commentView.setText(json2.getString(KEY_COMMENT));
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams commentViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                                    commentViewParams.setMargins(20, 10, 20, 20);
                                    commentView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.comment_bg);
                                     commentView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black)); 
                                    commentBox.addView(commentView, commentViewParams);





                            }//end if key is == 1
                        else{
                            // Error in registration
                            registerErrorMsg.setText(json2.getString(KEY_ERROR_MSG));
                        }//end else
                    }//end if
                } //end try

                catch (JSONException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }//end catch    
            }
        }
```

This code does not work but its an example of what I am trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is:
1. write a function that parses your json data and  initialise all required variables as global variables
2. run your function inside the doInBackground() method of AsyncTask without passing any parameters
3. set values to views from the onPostExecute() method